# How can I export separate node and edge files from single cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a single cypher query which will export to csv's: a node list and an edge list which can be analyzed by a library like `igraph`. I have my database set up with only a single relationship type:

```
(a:paper)-[:REFERENCES]->(b:paper)
```

I have multiple properties on each node (title, author etc.). The unique identifier is `paper_id`.

I've been trying to use the apoc functions `apoc.export.csv.query` and `apoc.export.csv.data`.

I can export the nodes and edges to a single file:

```
MATCH (n:paper)<-[r:REFERENCES]-(m:paper) WHERE n.paper_id = '1234'
WITH COLLECT(m) AS paper, COLLECT(r) AS references
CALL apoc.export.csv.data(
paper, 
references, 
'network.csv',
{}
) YIELD file, nodes, relationships
RETURN file, nodes, relationships
```

Or I can export just the edge list:

```
MATCH (n:paper)<-[r:REFERENCES]-(m:paper) WHERE n.paper_id = '1234' 
CALL apoc.export.csv.data(n.paper_id, m.paper_id, 'edge.csv', {})
WITH  n.paper_id AS From, m.paper_id AS To
;
```

Ideally, I would like a single query which would produce two files.

An edge list:

```
    From  | To
    1234  | 4567
    1234  | 8910
```

And a node list:

```
   paper_id | title           |  author
   1234     | "a title"       | "a name"
   4567     | "another title" | "another name"
   8910     | "a third title" | "third name"
```

Neo4j CE 3.4.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have much control over the format of `apoc.export.csv.data` (or any of its related functions) - you're pretty much always going to see internal node IDs (and all the other metadata) instead of just your desired unique values.

Still - assuming you can do some futzing about on the import side you *can* export two files, one with edges and one with nodes.

Assuming you want enough information in the `nodes.csv` file to recreate the graph - i.e. you need both the papers that reference `m` and you need `m`, and using the sample Movies database:

```
MATCH (movie: Movie { title: 'Top Gun' })<-[acted_in: ACTED_IN]-(actor: Person)
WITH collect(distinct actor) + movie as nodes, collect(distinct acted_in) as relationships
CALL apoc.export.csv.data([], relationships, 'edges.csv', {}) YIELD file as edgefile
CALL apoc.export.csv.data(nodes, [], 'nodes.csv', {}) YIELD file as nodefile
RETURN edgefile, nodefile
```

This yields two files in the `import` folder, with contents as below. It's not clear if this actually achieves what you want, since the only consistent identifier across the two files is the internal node ID (which is sufficient to rebuild an equivalent graph).

**nodes.csv**

```
"_id","_labels","born","name","released","tagline","title","_start","_end","_type"
"31",":Person","1959","Val Kilmer","","","",,,
"34",":Person","1961","Meg Ryan","","","",,,
"33",":Person","1933","Tom Skerritt","","","",,,
"30",":Person","1957","Kelly McGillis","","","",,,
"16",":Person","1962","Tom Cruise","","","",,,
"32",":Person","1962","Anthony Edwards","","","",,,
"29",":Movie","","","Top Gun","1986","I feel the need, the need for speed.",,,
```

**edges.csv**

```
"_id","_labels","_start","_end","_type","roles"
,,"16","29","ACTED_IN","[""Maverick""]"
,,"30","29","ACTED_IN","[""Charlie""]"
,,"31","29","ACTED_IN","[""Iceman""]"
,,"32","29","ACTED_IN","[""Goose""]"
,,"33","29","ACTED_IN","[""Viper""]"
,,"34","29","ACTED_IN","[""Carole""]"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked really well. Is there a way to modify the edge list file to use a node property instead of the internal id?

Comment: Not that I've found. I had thought you might get away with something similar to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Pablissimo/2f7e32989c61a8767b1a07849578f310), but it blows up in APOC when trying to save to CSV the virtual relationships created in the `apoc.create.vRelationships` call.